# How do you make Text value equal a Variable value using google apps script in the google documents?

Tags: javascript

im making a system to edit the text as a viewer,  but I can't figure it out!
Here's my code so far:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  DocumentApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Check')
      .addItem('Check', 'check')
      .addToUi();
}
```

```
 function check() {
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.prompt("Enter change text");
  Logger.log(result.getResponseText());
  Logger.getLog
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var qwerty = DocumentApp.insertText.insertText();
  
  
  }
```

I was expecting it to add text, but it just gave me an error.

Comment: How was this question relaetd to C language (I have removed the `C` tag) ?

Comment: The error message would be helpful. And oftentimes the start of a solution